# Why is the question about writing a polite unsubcribe email closed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, close-reasons

[How to write a polite unsubcribe email?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/19618/11428)

So Neil Fein thinks that this question is off-topic, and state to the meta question* he links, the reason it's closed is because it's asking for "what to write", not "how to write".

But but but but but..........

> If he does not know what to write about, we cannot help him anyway*.

I know the topic. Or do I have some ignorance? Please tell.

<sub>*[Should we be answering questions about what to write about?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/11428)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How to write" would be "Here is this email I have written. I think it is rude. Can you help me make it more polite?" That's working with existing copy.

"What to write" is "I want to accomplish X," whether X is a plot, an email, or a homework assignment. That's off-topic. We aren't going to choose the phrasing for you.

Comment: so you mean that all I need is a draft of what I'm about to write?

Comment: @Ooker Start there, yes, and give some context. "I'm sending it to so-and-so who is my boss/direct report/colleague etc. after receiving X number of emails and I've already done blah blah."