# Why was the question put on-hold: Rhethoric Mind Torture, how to write it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic

According to the super-useful notice at the bottom: off-topic.

Yeah, well then, let's focus more on how NGE handled the mind rape scene. I rewatch the scene and actually find what I was looking for. So, I focus on rhetorics and how they can be used in that format, that's got to be on-topic! *Right?*

And ever since the edits, there is absolute silence, no response, period.

Question is:
**A. Is my question alright now?**
**B. If not, then what should I edit to finally make it good?**

The question is [Rhethoric Mind Torture, how to write it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33646/rhethoric-mind-torture-how-to-write-it) (deleted, 2k rep required to view it)

Answer (score 8):

The edit didn't improve the question in any way that'd allow for re-opening. Questions asking what to write are firmly off-topic here. The links at the bottom of the closure notice will explain this in more detail.

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "This question appears to be off-topic because asking [what to write](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/397/26) or asking for help [rephrasing a sentence or passage](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536) are both off-topic here, as such questions are very unlikely to help anybody else." – Alexander, sudowoodo, FraEnrico, Secespitus, JP Chapleau
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please edit the question.

Comment: I still fail to understand it, What do you mean by "what to write"? I'm pretty sure it was a "what to keep in mind when I write?" type of question.

Answer (score 8):

The question is *too* specific, it isn't phrased in a way that lends itself to answers that would help anyone except you. It might have done better if it was recast to more of a general situation that many writers might clearly face.

Generally when you need to include lengthy background about your own story in order for people to understand your question, it's likely going to be considered off-topic.

With that said it's also possible the subject matter made people less willing to engage with it.  That itself isn't usually a reason for closing a question, but it does make it less likely someone will edit to fix it.