# What are Writers.SE's unique Close/Off-Topic reasons?

Tags: discussion, faq

The precise nature and scope of Writers.SE, as a Q&A resource for writers, is not always clear or intuitive to newcomers. Some types of questions seem appropriate, but through experience have been designated as off-topic.

**What are the categories of questions that Writers.SE has ruled off-topic, despite their relation to writing?  One reason per answer, please (to facilitate linking).**

This question should serve as a resource collecting the results and current status of Meta discussions, for easy reference and to help newcomers understand the site's unique policies.

Answer (score 5):

### Plot/Research Consultation

Writers.SE can help you with *how* to write, but not *what* to write. Writers.SE is not an appropriate for brainstorming plot ideas (brainstorming isn't Q&A) or for finding expertise in any non-writing subject (you might need historical research for your novel, but Writers.SE isn't about history questions).

### Further Reading:

- [Is a "Help me generate plot ideas?" or similar question on topic?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-a-help-me-generate-plot-ideas-or-similar-question-on-topic)
- [Is it appropriate to ask questions on specialist knowledge areas?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-on-specialist-knowledge-areas/)

Comment: I agree that questions about non-writing expertise are off-topic, but I think questions about how to do research in such areas can be on-topic.  Research is just another tool, in some ways.  But, as with all questions, the question need to show some effort; if it can be answered with a Wikipedia link or by saying "go to a library" that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

### *General* Critique Requests

> "Requests for **writing critiques** must include either a specific question about your sample or specific guidelines for the critique. See: [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)"

While critiques are some of the best help a writer can get, they are usually not appropriate questions for Writers.SE. This is because the basic format of a critique request is not "Question/Answer" or "Problem/Solution"; instead, it solicits a wide range of reactions to various elements of the text. This fits very poorly into the Q&A format. Please see further discussions on Meta *(TODO: add links)*.

Note that providing an excerpt of your work *within the context* of a direct question or a clear problem is perfectly fine. Avoid asking broad, opinion-soliciting questions such as:

- "Is this piece good?,"
- "How is my phrasing here?"
- "Does this flow well?"

Whereas the following questions are examples of direct, answerable questions:

- "Is this character's arrogance likeable, or annoying?"
- "How can I get rid of this infodump?"
- "This action scene feels boring; what can I do?"

### Further Reading:

- [What are the guidelines for asking for a critique of my work?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work)
- [Is [critique] a meta-tag?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-critique-a-meta-tag)

Answer (score 3):

### Rephrase Requests

> "Questions **asking for help rephrasing a sentence or passage** are off-topic as they're very unlikely to ever help anyone else. See: [Are requests for rephrasing on topic?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536)"

Requests to rephrase, rewrite, or edit some piece of writing. While helpful to the original poster, these tend to be unhelpful to anybody else - what we refer to as being "too localized."

### Further Reading:

- [Are requests for rephrasing on topic?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic)
- A specific subset is requests for proofreading or copyediting: [Should we allow grammar/proofreading questions?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions)