# How can we edit this question about military rank to be more on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [What rank should a US army officer be in order to funnel money into a shadowy corporation?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/23300/26) is an interesting one, but it's a particularly subjective question and falls afoul of a few rules here: [Plot/research consultation](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/718/26) in particular. It's also kind of a discussion question, not the sort of thing that's appropriate on a Q&A site.

I tried migrating it to Worldbuilding but [the first comment on the question there](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44300/what-rank-should-a-us-army-officer-be-in-order-to-funnel-money-into-a-shadowy-co#comment123967_44300) isn't hopeful about it being good for that site, either.

Can anyone suggest ways to edit this question so it's on-topic here? I'd hate to see this simply caught in the cracks because it's not *quite* appropriate for either site.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that its salvation may lie in the final sentence of the post:

> Alternatively, what are some good resources that I can use to research this sort of environment and answer this sort of question?

Possibly focusing on the research aspect, as opposed to asking the opinions of users as to what they would constitute as a reasonable plot point, would be more on-topic.

This could possibly be refined then into a question under the [research](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) tag. I think this would be quite useful as a question on techniques to research things involved with the military (or things in general where information may not be as freely available in the public domain) for purposes of accuracy, as plenty of pieces of writing involve the military, whether fiction or non-fiction, and could be helpful to many users.

Answer (score 0):

And asking it on a SE like [Militaria](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99463/militaria) (which is not even in beta yet) would likely draw some negative reactions too...

Note that the question received an answer on worldbuilding, maybe it'll be enough to answer it, even if it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would reword the question as: "What is the minimum rank at which a military officer would have sufficient authority to funnel a meaningful amount of money into a shadowy corporation?"

Answer: Colonel. He is a "column" commander with independent authority over a unit or a base. The criminal could have a higher rank, of course, but should not have a lower one (OK, maybe Lt. Colonel), unless the plot was that he was a fast-rising "prodigy."